# Python code working on terminal but not on web server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm executing these lines of code on python terminal and it is working but when i execute it on webserver which is xampp i get output 255 in transcribe_text.txt file but when i run through terminal i get audio to text proper conversion. I'm working on windows environment.

```
   import subprocess
    out=subprocess.getstatusoutput(['deepspeech', '--model', 'C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/output_graph.pb', '--lm', 'C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/lm.binary', '--trie', 'C:/deepspeech/deepspeech-0.6.0-models/trie', '--audio', 'C:/deepspeech/audio/8455-210777-0068.wav'])
    #open and read the file after the appending:
    print(str(out))
    f = open("transcribe_text.txt", "a")
    f.write(str(out))
    f.close()
    #open and read the file after the appending:
    f = open("transcribe_text.txt", "r")
    print(f.read())
```

Any solution Please, Thanks

Comment: Check if directory of `deepspeech` in `PATH` when run on xampp

Comment: @ShanavasM: I have placed  deepspeech files in C drive and xamp server is installed in c: drive can you please let me know how to resolve this issue, through terminal this code is being executed and in xampp also i can run python programs but issue is with this particular program

Comment: note: you shouldn't use `open()` and `f.close()` directly, use `with open("foobar") as f:` instead. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @d-k-bo: I tried it but it was also not working